# Bitnami Drupal can't send email

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04, drupal

I have the Bitnami Drupal AMI that is on the AWS marketplace.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/ref=bill_eml_1?sku=5ysj40wf1vkv5qwu3jszwhefa

when someone attemps to create a new account they get the following error:

Unable to send e-mail. Please contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitNami Drupal Amazon image is not configured by default to send emails. Amazon has a limit for sending email, you can check it at http://aws.amazon.com/en/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances

It is advisable to use an external SMTP provider (for example GMail or other) to send emails from the application. You can find how to configure it easily at http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Drupal#How_to_configure_the_email_settings_of_Drupal.3f

I hope it helps.